# UWP Telerik Charts Real Time Data (ie Live Data)

Tags: uwp, telerik

Can UWP Telerik Charts do a real time (ie live data) chart?  And if so is there a sample someone can point me to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Telerik charts can handle live data as any data added to the ObservableCollection that is bound to the chart will result in an update to the chart.  I was getting frustrated by some of the error messages coming back that weren't exactly helpful for finding and fixing the problem I was having.